# create directory from boost::filesystem succeeds, however no dir is created

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I have the following code, and although the call to `boost::filesystem::create_directory` returns `true`, I see no directory created in my project folder.

What could be the reason for this?

```
boost::filesystem::path dir("newdir");
if (boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir))
    std::cout << "Success" << "\n";
```

I'm using VS2008 and Win7 Home Premium.

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to write to the location, and are you certain exactly where it is writing it to, try using a full qualified path. eg "C:/users/docuemnts/whatever" or whatever the windows format is these days. Finally if I remember correctly the VS will try and execute that base on the folder it is running from which isn't always obvious in VS (again try fully qualifying the path)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could be suffering from [folder virtualization](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista). Also try creating a directory with the full path so that you are not affected by whatever **current application directory** is

Comment: It would be nice to include more material from the reference link, before it gets deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Could you be looking in the wrong place for it?  A quick call to `cout << current_path().string() << endl;` will show you where your directory is being created.